# How to disable throwExceptionIfCannotObtainLock in mongock

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb, mongock, mongobee

Used the traditional approach of running mongock -
https://www.mongock.io/quick-start#traditional-builder-approach

```
@Bean
public MongockSpring5.MongockInitializingBeanRunner changockSpring5(ApplicationContext springContext, MongoClient mongoClient) {
        SpringDataMongoV3Driver driver = SpringDataMongoV3Driver.withDefaultLock(
                new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, database));
        
        return MongockSpring5
                .builder()
                .setDriver(driver)
                .addChangeLogsScanPackage("com.abc.mongock.migration")
                .setSpringContext(springContext)
                .buildInitializingBeanRunner();
    }
```

How can we pass the config to set "throwExceptionIfCannotObtainLock" as false to this builder?

Answer (score 1):

we can set it like below by calling "dontFailIfCannotAcquireLock"

```
MongockSpring5
                .builder()
                .setDriver(driver)
                .addChangeLogsScanPackage("com.abc.mongock.migration")
                .setSpringContext(springContext)
                .dontFailIfCannotAcquireLock()
                .buildInitializingBeanRunner();
```